# Transaction has been reverted by the EVM while submiting transaction via web3Js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I have written a code to deploy a smart contract that takes two variables. Also given an account to sign the transaction so that the user does not have to directly interact with the contract. I have made the abi and the bytecode of the contract in some other file and it is also intact. But the transaction is getting reverted. And not executed. Can you help me in that.The code fo that particular file is-

```
    const Web3 = require('web3')
const contract = require('../contracts')

const network = {
    rinkeby: "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2cf3ec9bd42d4099b8620c2a6ee8c51a",
    ropsten: "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/2cf3ec9bd42d4099b8620c2a6ee8c51a",
    quorum: "http://127.0.0.1:22000"
}
//34.213.150.192
const web3 = {
    'rinkeby': new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(network.rinkeby)),
    'quorum': new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(network.quorum)),
    'ropsten': new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(network.ropsten))
}

const keystore = {
    rinkeby: {
        address: "0x0b5E74f4cD6c78C1963D02db25a68e4f3d2CDe0E",
        privateKey: "040C8FB1D157D0F7E3B6F29A41F9A90FC16D63D4273D221432BBCB7EB52862BB"
    },
    ropsten: {
        address: "0x232D1038Ca6d21DF85F2109E6155E3f7c0Eea808",
        privateKey: "dd3853d79745bd65a3a2691052e9fe27c39a314e45780b389e5ceb236d615f6c"
    },
    local: {
        address: "0x9347ebf55cdb7d00b43f57d25f4e2c01b7c3a174",
        privateKey: "273067fc6f762112438589da72b96e150ba1618cf01eee93975daab4076e49c0"
    },
    quorum: {
        address: "0x41ad2bc63a2059f9b623533d87fe99887d794847",
        privateKey: "e3b0c44298fc2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
 }

const AuthoxCoreContract = {

    'rinkeby': new web3.rinkeby.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contract.address.rinkeby, {
        from: keystore.rinkeby.address,
        gas: 3000000,
    }),

    'ropsten': new web3.ropsten.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contract.address.ropsten, {
        from: keystore.ropsten.address,
        gas: 3000000,
    }),

    'quorum': new web3.quorum.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contract.address.quorum, {
        from: keystore.quorum.address,
        gas: 10000000,
    })
}

var chainName = "ropsten"

let data = 'bytecode'

const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const privateKey = new Buffer.from(keystore[chainName].privateKey, 'hex')


web3[chainName].eth.getTransactionCount(keystore[chainName].address)
    .then(nonce => {
        console.log(nonce)
        const rawTx = {
            nonce: nonce,
            gasPrice: chainName === 'quorum' ? 0 : 9000000000,
            gasLimit: 4300000,
            from: keystore[chainName].address,

            data: data
        }

        const tx = new Tx(rawTx, {
            chain: 'ropsten',
            hardfork:
                "homestead"
        });

        tx.sign(privateKey);

        const serializedTx = tx.serialize()



        web3[chainName].eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' +
            serializedTx.toString('hex'))
            .on('transactionHash', function (hash) {
                console.log(`hash: ${hash}`)
            })
            .on('receipt', function (receipt) {
                console.log(`receipt: ${JSON.stringify(receipt)}`)
                console.dir(receipt)
            })
            .on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
                console.log(`confirmationNumber: ${confirmationNumber}, receipt: ${receipt} `)
                //return resolve(receipt)
            })
            .on('error', function (error) {
                console.error("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx")
                console.error(error)
                //return reject(error)
            }) 
    })
```

**The OutPut that comes out is -**

[image]

Comment: Please provide your smart contract code.